# To which systems do the Steamplay icons refer?

Tags: steam, steam-play

This may sound as a stupid question, but I just wanted to be sure.

Steamplay is an indicator on the Steam Store on which operating systems the game is officially supported.

Recently they've got ...

- Windows logo for Windows OS
- Apple logo for Mac OS
- Tux (penguin) for Linux OS

I've now searched the store and saw, that they seem to have the Tux replaced with the Steam logo:

[image]

The Steamplay information site still has Tux as the Linux reference listed, that's why I'm asking.

**Am I right that the Steam logo represents SteamOS, which then means that this icon stands for "supporting Linux systems"?**

Answer (score 2):

Steamplay only means : 'When you buy this game it will be available for all the listed plateforms without extra cost.'

It doesn't mean : 'this game will be availble for linux in addition to supported/listed plateform'. For istance [Stasis](http://store.steampowered.com/app/380150/) is Steamplay and only available for PC and Mac

In your screenshot there is the steamplay logo because when you buy this game you will get both PC, SteamOS and Mac version.

Take a look at [steamplay documentation](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9439-QHKN-1308)

From this documentation :

> Steam Play allows you to purchase your games once and play anywhere. Whether you have purchased your Steam Play enabled game on a Mac or PC (both Windows and Linux), you will be able to play on the other platform free of charge.

Comment: Nope, there must be a difference. For example this game only has Apple+Windows icon, not the Steam icon: http://store.steampowered.com/app/375950/

Comment: The steam icon means SteamOS, the Steamplay icon is a commercial one which says 'purchase your games once and play anywhere' on the supported plateforms of the game.

Comment: So yes the steam icon means SteamOS thus linux :)

Comment: Thanks mate, that's what I wanted to know. But I guess your question is a little on cross-porpuse as my question. I wanted to know to which system each icon of the Steamplay icon (not itself) refers to. (Actually only which one's Linux, but asking it that way it's more complete.)

Comment: I'm still confused. I can't find any games anywhere on the Steam site with "Tux" (indicating playable on Linux) anymore. For example, I happen to know that this game: http://store.steampowered.com/app/219740/ plays on Ubuntu but I don't see the Tux icon on the game's page. However, I was under the impression that COD4 will not play on Linux in Steam, but it still has the Steamplay logo/icon: http://store.steampowered.com/app/7940/ Is there any way to tell which games play on Linux/Ubuntu?

Comment: The tux logo has been replaced by the steam OS logo like on the image associated with the question. As I say before : "So yes the steam icon means SteamOS thus linux :)"